# Transform several Dataframe rows into a single row

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The following is an example Dataframe snippet:

```
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|_lid               |trace                           |message                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|1103960793391132675|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|[app.py:208] Prediction label: {"id": 617, "name": "CENSORED"}, score=0.3874854505062103                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|1103960793391132676|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|[app.py:224] Similarity values: [0.6530804801919593, 0.6359653379418201]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           |
|1103960793391132677|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|[app.py:317] Predict=s3://CENSORED/scan_4745/scan4745_t1_r0_c9_2019-07-15-10-32-43.jpg trait_id=112 result=InferenceResult(predictions=[Prediction(label_id='230', label_name='H3', probability=0.0), Prediction(label_id='231', label_name='Other', probability=1.0)], selected=Prediction(label_id='231', label_name='Other', probability=1.0)). Took 1.3637824058532715 seconds |
+-------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

I have millions of these, log like structures, where they all can be grouped by trace which is unique to a session.

I'm looking to transform these sets of rows into single rows, essentially mapping over them, for for this example I would extract from the first name the `"id": 617` from the second row the values `0.6530804801919593, 0.6359653379418201` and from the third row the `Prediction(label_id='231', label_name='Other', probability=1.0)` value.

Then I would compose a new table having the columns:

```
| trace | id | similarity | selected |
```

with the values:

```
| 47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c | 617 | 0.6530804801919593, 0.6359653379418201 | 231 |
```

How should I implement this group-map transform over several rows in pyspark ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using something in the lines of

```
expected_schema = StructType([
   StructField("event_timestamp", TimestampType(), False),
   StructField("trace", StringType(), False),
   ...
])

@F.pandas_udf(expected_schema, F.PandasUDFType.GROUPED_MAP)
# Input/output are both a pandas.DataFrame
def transform(pdf):
  output = {}

  for l in pdf.to_dict(orient='record'):
    x = re.findall(r'^(\[.*:\d+\]) (.*)', l['message'])[0][1]
    ...

  return pd.DataFrame(data=[output])

df.groupby('trace').apply(transform)
```

Answer (score 1):

I've written the below example in Scala for my own convenience, but it should translate readily to Pyspark.

1) Create the new columns in your dataframe via `regexp_extract` on the "message" field. This will produce the desired values if the regex matches, or empty strings if not:

```
scala> val dss = ds.select(
     | 'trace, 
     | regexp_extract('message, "\"id\": (\\d+),", 1) as "id", 
     | regexp_extract('message, "Similarity values: \\[(\\-?[0-9\\.]+, \\-?[0-9\\.]+)\\]", 1) as "similarity", 
     | regexp_extract('message, "selected=Prediction\\(label_id='(\\d+)'", 1) as "selected"
     | )
dss: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [trace: string, id: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> dss.show(false)
+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------+--------+
|trace                           |id |similarity                            |selected|
+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------+--------+
|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|617|                                      |        |
|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|   |0.6530804801919593, 0.6359653379418201|        |
|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|   |                                      |231     |
+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------+--------+
```

2) Group by "trace" and eliminate the cases where the regex didn't match. The quick and dirty way (show below) is to select the `max` of each column, but you might need to do something more sophisticated if you expect to encounter more than one match per trace:

```
scala> val ds_final = dss.groupBy('trace).agg(max('id) as "id", max('similarity) as "similarity", max('selected) as "selected")
ds_final: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [trace: string, id: string ... 2 more fields]

scala> ds_final.show(false)
+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------+--------+
|trace                           |id |similarity                            |selected|
+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------+--------+
|47c10fda9b40407c998c154dc71a9e8c|617|0.6530804801919593, 0.6359653379418201|231     |
+--------------------------------+---+--------------------------------------+--------+
```